# Typescript cast missing expected property in cast

Tags: typescript

In this [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20hi()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%60hi%20%24%7Bthis.y%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20new%20X()%3B%0D%0Aa.y%20%3D%20'bob'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20%7B%20y%3A%20'ham'%20%7D%20as%20X%3B%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20Object.assign(new%20X()%2C%20b)%3B%0D%0Adocument.write(a.hi)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ouputs%20%22hi%20bob%22%0D%0Adocument.write(%22%3Cbr%3E%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.write((b.hi%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined).toString())%3B%20%2F%2F%20outputs%20%22true%22%0D%0Adocument.write(%22%3Cbr%3E%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.assign(b%2C%20X.prototype)%3B%0D%0Adocument.write((b.hi%20!%3D%3D%20undefined).toString())%3B%20%2F%2F%20outputs%20%22true%22%0D%0Adocument.write(%22%3Cbr%3E%22)%3B%0D%0Adocument.write(b.hi)%3B%20%2F%2F%20outputs%20%22hi%20defined%22%20--%20want%20%22hi%20ham%22%0D%0Adocument.write(%22%3Cbr%3E%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.write(c.hi)%3B%20%2F%2F%20outputs%20%22hi%20ham%22%0D%0Adocument.write(%22%3Cbr%3E%22)%3B) I'm trying to cast an object literal to an object with a property. That is not working as expected.

```
class X {
    y: string;
    get hi(): string {
        return `hi ${this.y}`;
    }
}

const a = new X();
a.y = 'bob';

const b = { y: 'ham' } as X;
const c = Object.assign(new X(), b);
document.write(a.hi); // ouputs "hi bob"
document.write("<br>");

document.write((b.hi === undefined).toString()); // outputs "true"
document.write("<br>");

Object.assign(b, X.prototype);
document.write((b.hi !== undefined).toString()); // outputs "true"
document.write("<br>");
document.write(b.hi); // **outputs "hi defined" -- want "hi ham"**
document.write("<br>");

document.write(c.hi); // outputs "hi ham"
document.write("<br>");
```

Is there something I'm missing in the cast to make this work, or should I just `Object.assign` like I'm doing with the `const c = Object.assign(new X(), { y: 'ham' });`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I just Object.assign like I'm doing with the const c = Object.assign(new X(), { y: 'ham' });

Yes.

Ideally though you would take it in the constructor:

```
class X {
    constructor(public y: string){}
    get hi(): string {
        console.log(this);
        return `hi ${this.y}`;
    }
}
```

`Object.assign` and class instances *do not mix well*. Use it only for `object literals`.